# Android error cannot find symbol

Tags: java, android

guys! I had problem with this error ***java: cannot find symbol*** in my android application project recently. I don't know where is the error that made the problem. Here is my file details:

***navigation_bar_layout.xml*** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/navigation_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#515151"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
<!--Back-->
<ImageView android:id="@+id/back_icon"
           android:layout_width="50dp"
           android:layout_height="50dp"
           android:padding="5dp"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:src="@drawable/back_icon"/>
<!--Title-->
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
<!--Menu-->
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

***NavigationBar.java*** :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;    

public class NavigationBar extends RelativeLayout implements OnClickListener{
public NavigationBar(Context context){
    this(context, null);
}

private ImageView backImageView;
private TextView titleView;
private ImageView menuImageView;

public NavigationBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);

    View view     = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.navigation_bar_layout, this, true);
    backImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.back_icon);
    titleView     = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    menuImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.menu);

    backImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
    menuImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
}


public ImageView getBackImageView(){ return backImageView; }
public TextView getTitleView(){ return titleView; }
public ImageView getMenuImageView(){ return menuImageView; }

public void setTitle(String title){ titleView.setText(title); }

private ClickCallBack clickCallBack;
public void setClickCallBack(ClickCallBack clickCallBack){ this.clickCallBack = clickCallBack; }
public static interface ClickCallBack{
    void onBackClick();     
    void onMenuClick();     
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    if(id == R.id.back_icon){
        clickCallBack.onBackClick();
        return;
    }
    if(id == R.id.menu){
        clickCallBack.onMenuClick();
        return;
    }
  }
}
```

And, here is ***error console*** :

```
Error:(24, 9) java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   variable backImageView
location: class com.example.MyFirstAndroidApp.NavigationBar
Error:(24, 37) java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   variable view
location: class com.example.MyFirstAndroidApp.NavigationBar
Error:(25, 36) java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   variable view
location: class com.example.MyFirstAndroidApp.NavigationBar
Error:(26, 37) java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   variable view
location: class com.example.MyFirstAndroidApp.NavigationBar
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Clean your project before run

Comment: one thing I see is, that You give Your RelativeLayout the attribut layout_alignParentTop, but this RelativeLayout seems to be the parent...

Comment: But I guess You have imported the wrong R. file. (or none). if there is an import android.R, delete it and import Your R. file..

Comment: CLEAN REBUILD and set `inflate(R.layout.navigation_bar_layout, null);`

Comment: Well, @IntelliJ Amiya it's maybe really a good way,  after I had applied ***inflate(R.layout.navigation_bar_layout, null);*** the **view symbol error** fixed but **backImageView symbol error** still comes.

Comment: use `public` instead of `private`

Comment: `this(context, null);` why null parameter ?

Comment: okay ,Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean

Comment: @frankjorsn let me inform

Comment: Well, thanks @IntelliJ Amiya ! I don't know where is problem, but when I re-format my code, the error fixed, I suppose it's maybe the **comments or whitespace** that caused the problem. Thanks anyway. And I'm wonder the difference between the **inflate(R.layout.navigation_bar_layout, null)** with **inflate(R.layout.navigation_bar_layout, this, true)** ?

Comment: @frankjorsn Glad to see that works .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)** is the term used within the context of Android to indicate when an XML layout resource is parsed and converted into a hierarchy of View objects.

You should try with

```
 View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.navigation_bar_layout,null);
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild`** Your Project .

For your Second question , You should check **[Layout Inflation as Intended](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/)**

Comment: Well, although I have not a absolute clear understanding of the difference between them, and I will take a lot of time to read the API carefully. Anyway, thanks so much!